# How to call a multidimensional prediction on a keras model with a javascript api

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I have trained a model based on the keras [lstm_text_generation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py) example, and I would like to perform predictions on this model with front-end javascript.

First I tried using [keras.js](https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js), however that only takes 1-dimensional `Float32Array` vectors in it's prediction function so I am unable to use it since the lstm_text_generation example uses a multidimensional array of shape `(1, maxlen, len(chars))`.

Next I tried using [tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/), using [this tutorial](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html) to port my keras model to a `model.json` file. Everything seems to work fine, up to the point where I perform the actual prediction where it freezes and gives me the warning `Orthogonal initializer is being called on a matrix with more than 2000 (65536) elements: Slowness may result.`

I noticed that in many of the tensorflow.js examples, people convert their arrays to `tensor2d`, but I did this and it had no effect on the performance of my code.

For anyone curious, here is the javascript code I wrote...

```
async function predict_from_model() {
  const model = await tf.loadModel('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/98mprice/death-grips-lyrics-generator/master/model.json');
  try {
    var seed = "test test test test test test test test"
    var maxlen = 40
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      var x_pred = nj.zeros([1, maxlen, 61]).tolist()
      for (var j = 0; j < seed.length; j++) {
        x_pred[0][j][char_indices[seed.charAt(j)]] = 1
      }
      console.log("about to predict") 
      const preds = model.predict(x_pred) //gets stuck here
      console.log("prediction done")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

...to perform the same function as `on_epoch_end()` in the `lstm_text_generation.py` example. The output of `x_pred` is the same in both python and javascript code, so I don't think the issue lies there.

I think I need to make some optimisations in `tensorflow.js`, but I'm not sure what. Does anyone know how to fix any of my issues above and/or any other javascript library that would work for my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x_pred` needs to be a tensor, the simplest way to create a tensor with custom values is [`tf.buffer`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#buffer), which can be initialized with a `TypedArray` or can be modified using [`.set()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#tf.TensorBuffer.set) which would be better for you, because most of your values are 0 and buffer are filled with zeros by default. And to create a tensor out of a buffer just use [`.toTensor()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#tf.TensorBuffer.toTensor);

So it would something like this:

```
var x_pred = tf.buffer([1, maxlen, 61]);
for (var j = 0; j < seed.length; j++) {
  x_pred.set(1, 0, j, char_indices[seed.charAt(j)]);
}
console.log("about to predict") 
const preds = model.predict(x_pred.toTensor());
console.log("prediction done")
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't get your code working but I just put my raw array in a tensor3d and it worked

Comment: It got stuck at the set method, and I don't really know anything about tensorflow so I'm not sure... sorry. I assume your way is the correct way to do this though, so it was helpful to me so I know for the future.

Comment: If you look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/0cb81e80319ff7f79257556d88ce70cfb548c9fd/src/tensor.ts#L66-L77) you can even call `.set()` with rest parameters like `.set(val, x, y, z)`. Maybe this would work. But thanks for accepting the answer anyway